# Remove objects from array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to remove objects from an array of object using a delta data i'm getting from server. I'm using underscore in my project.

Is there a straight forward way to do this, rather  going with looping and assigning ?

Main Array

```
var input = [
   {name: "AAA", id: 845,status:1},
   {name: "BBB", id: 839,status:1},
   {name: "CCC", id: 854,status:1}
];
```

Tobe Removed

```
var deltadata = [
   {name: "AAA", id: 845,status:0},
   {name: "BBB", id: 839,status:0}
];
```

Expected output

```
var finaldata =  [
  {name: "CCC", id: 854,status:1}
]
```

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.filter` with a predicate that performs a `.indexOf` on the other array.

Comment: What's a delta data? @BenjaminGruenbaum - Could you show an example with indexOf and objects ?

Comment: @adeneo Delta is a common term for 'difference' or subtraction - in this case, element subtraction. OP wants to remove all elements from `input` that do not appear in `deltadata` - either based on structural equality (in which case you'd `.map(JSON.stringify)` before performing a .indexOf and stringify the value too, or reference equality - in which case you'd use a simple `.indexOf`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I'm really not getting it, how would you use indexOf for that? Could you post an example, I'm really asking because I'm curious as to how something like that would work? I would think you'd have to compare the ID's or something, as two objects can't be compared with indexOf, and even if you stringify them there's no guarantee they will be equal, even if they contain the exact same things ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum—a simple indexOf won't work because comparing objects will always be false, and JSON.stringify won't be reliable because objects with the same name/value pairs may be returned in a different order. The OP will need to loop over each property in each object to test equality (unless equality depends on just one name/value pair).

Comment: What would you base the removal on of on object on?  `name`? `id`?  The `status` values are different, so even if they weren't objects (which will never match), the values still wouldn't "match" between `input` and `deltadata`.

Comment: @adeneo meh, it works in v8 and other current engine and it won't change any time soon. I agree with the criticism though. You can always use `_.equals` instead as this question is tagged underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. As others have mentioned, I don't think this is possible without a loop. You could also add checks for status and name in the condition, as this just compares IDs.

```js
var finaldata = input.filter(function(o) {
    for (var i = 0; i < deltadata.length; i++)
       if (deltadata[i].id === o.id) return false;
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var finaldata = _.filter(input, function(item) {
    return !(_.findWhere(deltadata, {id: item.id}));
});
```

It does assume that you have unique ID's. Maybe you can come up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `filter` will do it:

```
var finaldata = _.filter(input, function(o) {
    return _.findWhere(deltadata, o) === undefined;
});
```

A little more efficient than the `findWhere` would be creating a lookup map with ids to remove, and then filtering by that:

```
var idsToRemove = _.reduce(deltadata, function(m, o) {
    m[o.id] = true;
    return m;
}, {});
var finaldata = _.reject(input, function(o) { return o.id in idsToRemove; });
```

Comment: if you compare both input and delta data status field value is going to differ.

Your second update looks promising, let me test it out :)

Comment: uh, I had expected a `delta` to be "the things that are removed". You still could do a `_.findWhere(deltadata, _.pick(o, "name", "id"))` or something.